# What does $e^{-\pi/2}$ being the principal value of $i^i$ mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What does it mean to say that the principal value of $i^i$ is $e^{-\pi/2}$? Are there other values as well?

Comment: Usually for the argument of a complex number, the angle is chosen to be between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ This results in the principal value. Are there other arguments? Sure, if you pick a multiple of $2\pi$ onto the given argument

Comment: @imranfat can you give another value of $i^i$?

Comment: The argument in question here is $\pi/2$ because $i$ is on the positive y-axis. For the sake of argument, one could choose for the argument $5\pi/2$ (by adding a multiple of $2\pi$). But we choose not to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for any $\phi$, $e^{i\phi} = e^{i\phi + 2\pi i}$, the expressions for $i$ can be $e^{i\pi/2 + 2\pi i k}$, where $k$ is an integer. Thus
$$ i^i = e^{i(\pi/2 + 2\pi k) i} = e^{2\pi k - \pi / 2}, k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Taking principal branch means that the angle $\pi/2 + 2\pi k$ is restricted to $(-\pi,\pi]$, or $k = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, so if $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}2+k\pi$, $\cos\theta=0,\sin\theta=\pm1$ and $e^{i(\pi/2+k\pi)}=(-1)^ki$.

The principal value is then with $k=0$.